# How to round down a float to the nearest value that can be divided by two without rest?

Tags: objective-c, c

For example I have a float 55.2f and want to round it down such that the result can be divided by two without rest.

So 55.2 would become 54 as that is the nearest smaller "step" that can be divided by two. Is there a function for this or must I write my own algorithm?

Comment: Your title says "round to nearest", but your question text and your example say "round down". You might also want to clarify between "round towards zero" and "round towards negative infinity" if the input can be negative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your result must remain a `float`, you can do:

```
float f=55.2f;
f=floorf(f/2.f)*2.f;
```

Comment: +1, because this solution is graceful when the value of the input exceeds `INT_MAX`.

Comment: This is by far the best answer; it is correct over the entire input range.  The answers that use conversion to integer are not.

Answer (score 3):

First convert to an integral type, such as `int` or `long`, and then clear the lowest bit.

```
float f = 55.2f;
int   i = (int)f & ~1;
```

---

**Explanation**

`~` means the bitwise inverse, i.e. all the `0` bits become `1`, and vice versa.

So, if `1` has the bit pattern

```
0...0001
```

then `~1` is

```
1...1110
```

(Here I'm using `...` to represent all the in-between bits depending on how big an integer is on your platform.)

When you `&` (bitwise AND) your integer with `1...1110`, you are preserving the value of each bit apart from the lowest bit, which is forced to `0`. See [this description of the bitwise AND operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) if you still don't get it.

By forcing the lowest bit to be `0`, you are rounding the number down to the nearest even number.

Comment: can you expand upon your answer?  I was not familiar with the ~ operand, and after looking it up, I still don't understand your answer. Why isn't ~1 the same as 0?

Comment: Ah, now I see -- just didn't realize that ~1 doesn't just invert the 1 but the whole representation, 0000...1.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own algorithm, for example with bitwise operators.

The following code works with clearing the last bit of your number. An even number has indeed the last bit not set.

```
int 
f(float x) 
{ 
    return (int)x & ~1; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about `long int f = lrintf(x / 2);`, where `x` is your float?

You could also just say `int f = x / 2;`, but some people have argued that that's more expensive, because the C standard mandates a specific rounding mode which may or may not be native to the CPU. The `lrintf` function on the other hand uses the CPU's native rounding mode. You need to `#include <math.h>`.